# Netbeans 7.1 won't open

Tags: netbeans, crash

I recently installed netbeans on windows 7 x64 and it was working fine till today. The splash screen would show up and saying loading modules then just close.

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete

```
(user)/AppData/Netbeans
```

I was fed up... It worked though :)

Answer (score 1):

Just deleting the lock file at

```
(user)/AppData/Netbeans/7.3.1/
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your [userdir](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir) is corrupted, you can test this by using a clean userdir - see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqAlternateUserdir

Comment: So what do you do if you find out that the userdir is corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your JDK? If so then your JDK might be broken. Try reinstalling the JDK and change the netbeans_jdkhome property in \etc\netbeans.conf

I have also faced this issue, and this solved my problem.