# Netbeans 7.0.1 dosent start even after deleting the folder

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-8

I have uninstalled netbeans 8 and installed 7.0.1 version. After Installation when I open it the screen says "Loading cached modules" and closes automatically, No error shown.

I tried deleting the folder in user/appdata/local/netbeans but yet it didn't work ([Netbeans 7.1 won't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442857/netbeans-7-1-wont-open)).

Running Win 7 64

Answer (score 0):

Check Which Java version you used ? if Java 8, uninstall and  install Java 7 then try.